# CURSOR...IF...CURSOR..else condition

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

I am trying to use the Cursor FOR loop inside a IF condition and getting error.
Here are the details:

```
OPEN c_tab_var FOR v_sql;
 Loop
fetch c_tab_var into v_cur_inv_var;
exit when c_tab_var%notfound;

For v_cur_bde IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT BDE.col1, BDE.col2
    FROM   tab BDE
    ORDER BY BDE.col1, BDE.col2, BDE.col3....
)

LOOP 
If v_cur_bde.col1 = v_cur_inv_var.col1 AND v_cur_bde.col2 = v_cur_inv_var.col2 THEN
(
    FOR v_cur_var IN
   (
      SELECT.....
   )
   LOOP
   -
   -
   -
)
ELSE
(
    -
  -
    -
)
END IF;
```

Here is the error I am getting:

Compilation errors for PROCEDURE ABC

Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FOR" when expecting one of the following:

```
      ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
      <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
      continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
      sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
      date <a string literal with character set specification>
      <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
      <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>
      <an alternative
```

Line: 57
Text: FOR v_cur_var IN

Error: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:

```
      ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
      null pragma raise return select update while with
      <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
      <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock
      insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
      merge pipe purge
```

Line: 210
Text: )

ANY HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED!!!!

Comment: Exclude "(" and ")" from IF THEN ELSE END IF; statement. See the documentation of the syntax: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/if_statement.htm

Comment: Get yourself familiar with the language syntax, please.

Answer (score 0):

well, you just have tons of syntax errors. You start three loops, but there not one "end loop" in there for instance.

The closest I can get to something without syntax errors is this:

> BEGIN    OPEN c_tab_var FOR v_sql;
>
> LOOP
>         FETCH c_tab_var INTO   v_cur_inv_var;
>
> ```
>   EXIT WHEN c_tab_var%NOTFOUND;
>
>   FOR v_cur_bde IN (  SELECT   DISTINCT BDE.col1, BDE.col2
>                         FROM   tab BDE
>                     ORDER BY   BDE.col1, BDE.col2, BDE.col3)
>   LOOP
>      IF v_cur_bde.col1 = v_cur_inv_var.col1
>         AND v_cur_bde.col2 = v_cur_inv_var.col2
>      THEN
>         FOR v_cur_var IN (SELECT   1 FROM DUAL) --add your select statement for this loop
>         LOOP
>            NULL; --do something
>         END LOOP;
>      ELSE
>         NULL; -- do something else
>      END IF;
>   END LOOP;    END LOOP; END;
> ```

but without knowing the context, it's impossible to properly answer this question